Switch to another python version in Jupyter and in VS Code
I am using a Langchain to create a LLM in python version 3.12.4. However, I am getting an error mentioned below:
TypeError: ForwardRef._evaluate() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'recursive_guard' while importing from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter. I have decided to switch to the lower version of Python (3.11) according to the answer given in text.
But I would like to know how can I switch to the different version of python (from 3.12 to 3.11) to successfully run Langchain without an error.
I tried installing 3.11.9, created a Virtual Enviornment called Langchain, activated it. but now I want to write my code by acrivating a Python version 3.11.9. However the Jupyter notebook still shows the active version 3.12.4.

Did you install Jupyter into the new virtual environment and connect the kernel to the correct Python for Jupyter?

While in the virtual environment, when you have it activated in your console, what do you get with python --version. Python can have multiple versions installed alongside each other. You need to select the correct version when you create the environment, or remove the unwanted 3.12 version to avoid this issue.

Here and errorLogger's comment here may provide more context and help.

maybe you have to run it as python3.11 -m jupyter notebook but first you have to instal jupyter in this version python3.11 -m pip install jupyter. On Linux you may have commands python3.11 and python3.12 to run selected version. On WIndows it may need to search in folders python3.11/python.exe and python3.12/python.exe - (but I don't use Windows so I can't confirm it)
